# Send an arraylist to my activity by onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I retrieve arraylist with AsyncTask

```
 protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<User> result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    SupCrowdfunderActivity.pro2 = result;
    Log.e("5",SupCrowdfunderActivity.pro2.toString());
 }
```

I can see the result have object. But why I can't retrieve the array in my SupCrowactivity.

```
 mUdao= DaoFactory.retreiveUserDaoFactory();
 mUdao.retrieveAlluserById(id);
 Log.e("t",pro2)
```

The tag t is null.

Comment: Are you sure the AsyncTask has finished?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Currentclass.this, Targetclass.class);
intent.putExtra("result", result);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in your Targetclass activity call the following:

```
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("result");
```

To avoid `NullPointerException` use a `NullPointer` `try catch`